# Linear Layout problem in android

Tags: android

I need an android UI exactly like the this link.
require screen
https://picasaweb.google.com/altafcs/Android#5579082089055802882

I am using LinearLayout with horizontal orientation.I want to place a third image overlayed over these two images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to user `RelativeLayout` as you root layout, place your current `LinearLayout` as first item, and overlayed image as a second one. Specifi parameters you needed to correctly place overlayed image.

Answer (score 0):

You need a to put the LinearLayout you already have within another layout. Place your image there and make it fill_parent in height and width.